# Trapcode Form - imported OBJ has additional unwanted edges

Tags: after-effects, plugins

I created the below semi-truncated octahedron in blender and exported the object has a .obj file for use in Trapcode Form.

[image]

However, when I import the model into Trapcode Form and select `Particles From: Edges`, the below shape is rendered.

[image]

As you can hopefully see, it has added two bisecting lines to each of the truncated faces (one horizontal one vertical), as well as adding additional asymmetrical edges below each truncated face.

I have viewed my .obj in multiple viewers, both as solid and mesh, and none of them show these edges existing. Is there a way to prevent these from being created in Trapcode Form? I'm a little lost as to what could be causing this.

Comment: I believe that Form works from vertices not edges, so it is just looking for the nearest vertices and drawing lines between the points. I’m not sure that there is a way to control this.